# Printing a heartbeat (heart star) animation

Tags: c, console

Here is a C program to print a heart star animation using a `while` loop [written by myself](https://github.com/albert10jp/c_learning/blob/main/heart_star_animation.c).

I've tested it on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) and [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

To animate it, I print a sequence of heart star patterns in different sizes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, h, k = 0;

    while (k < 99) {
        /* code */
        h = k % 3;
        printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
        printf("\e[?25l");

        i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            j = 0;
            while (j < (2 - i) * 2 + h) {
                printf(" ");
                j++;
            }

            j = 0;
            while (j < (i + 2) * 2 - h * 2) {
                printf("* ");
                j++;
            }

            j = 0;
            while (j < (2 - i) * 2 + 1 + h) {
                printf("  ");
                j++;
            }

            j = 0;
            while (j < (i + 2) * 2 - h * 2) {
                printf("* ");
                j++;
            }

            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < 9) {
            j = 0;
            while (j < i * 2 + h * 2) {
                printf(" ");
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
            while (j < 17 - i * 2 - h * 4) {
                printf("* ");
                j++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }

        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(200000);
        k++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Welcome to CodeReview! The program doesn't look too bad, however there are some ways to improve it:

## Naming things

The biggest issue with your code is that there is a bunch of single-letter variable names (`i`...`k`), some magic constants (`2`, `3`, `4`, `17` and `99`), and nested `while`-loops. If I wasn't told what this program would do and didn't run it for myself, I would have no clue reading this code what it is going to do. However, if you would give (better) names to things, it might explain what everything means to the reader. That includes you yourself in the future!

Let's start with the outer loop:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
         int size = i % 3;
         clear_screen();
         draw_heart(size);
         usleep(200000);
    }
}
```

Keeping `i` as a generic loop counter is OK, as this is so commonplace that a longer name is not going to make this more readable. But I renamed `h` to `size`. Then I assume you have created two functions, one for clearing the screen, and another for drawing a heart of a given size. If you now read this code, you can very quickly see that you are repeatedly drawing a heart of a varying size, without requiring any comments.

Here is the function to clear the screen:

```
void clear_screen(void) {
    // Use ANSI escape codes to clear the screen
    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    printf("\e[?25l");
}
```

The name of the function alone is already enough to know what the function tries to do, the comment here is to explain the weird characters that are printed. Someone who doesn't recognize these escape codes now knows what these are, and can search for "ANSI escape codes" to find out more about them.

The constants you have in your code could be given names, like so:

```
void draw_heart(int size) {
    static const int top_size = 3;
    static const int bottom_size = 9;
    ...
}
```

And then used consistently in the calculations you use, such that if you want to change the size of the heart, you can just change these constants.

## Use `for`-loops where appropriate

You are using a lot of `while`-loops in cases where you can more clearly write `for`-loops. Any time you initialize a variable, run `while` the variable satisfies some condition, and then update that variable, use `for`, like so:

```
void draw_heart(int size) {
    // Draw two small upward pointing triangles
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < (2 - i) * 2 + size; j++) {
           printf(" ");
        }

        ...
    }

    // Draw one large downward pointing triangle
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The advantage is that in one line you combine all this information, so just from reading that line you can see what the start condition is, what the end condition is and how the variable is updated every step.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to write raw terminal codes to output, I'd advise encapsulating that into a well-named function.  Few of us can tell by looking exactly what effect `\e[1;1H\e[2J\e[?25l` will have.

There's a lot of use of `while` loops that, while not functionally incorrect, would be more idiomatically written as `for` loops, enabling other developers to read and understand the code more quickly.  E.g.

> ```
>             j = 0;
>             while (j < (2 - i) * 2 + h) {
>                 printf(" ");
>                 j++;
>             }
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
            for (int j = 0;  j < (2 - i) * 2 + h;  j++) {
                printf(" ");
            }
```

It might be worth giving a name to the calculation `(2 - i) * 2 + h` here.

If we know the upper bound for that value, we could avoid the loop, by printing a substring of a larger string:

```
char many_spaces[90];  /* my guess at largest bound */
memset(many_spaces, ' ', sizeof many_spaces);
...
printf("%.*s", (2 - i) * 2 + h, many_spaces);
```

A similar trick could be used for the other loops that repeat the same string many times.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from anything else, like how you might want to save your output as a string and print that, the `usleep()` function is deprecated and has been removed from version 4 of the Single Unix Specification.

Either use `nanosleep()`, or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` and `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to values that will select a version of the system libraries that still supports `usleep()`.  Otherwise, your source might not compile.  I’d recommend changing to `nanosleep()` and also specifying the feature-test macros for it.

So:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* ... */

  static const struct timespec to_sleep_200ms = {
    .tv_sec = 0,
    .tv_nsec = 200000000
  };
  
  nanosleep( &to_sleep_200ms, NULL );
```

In theory, defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is enough, but defining both is good defensive coding in case someone later defines only the other.  For example, if you had specified only `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` for an older version and someone later compiled with `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`, that would remove the declaration of `usleep()` and your program would no longer compile.  So, specify both.  That way, if anyone ever merges in a version clash, you’ll get a compilation error immediately that tells you what the bug is.

In a project with more than one source file, you probably want to move the feature-test macros into a new header file or the makefile.

Comment: At least in glibc stdio is buffered internally so there shouldn't be a need to buffer the output in the program itself.

Comment: @JanDorniak The overhead is small, but there’s really no need to generate the output and buffer it all over again on every iteration.

Comment: True that. There are like three variations. Traditional speed vs memory trade-off.

Comment: @JanDorniak Exactly. There’s a genuine trade-off, so I just suggest it as something to consider. On a modern system with gigabytes of RAM, I’d pretty much always trade off this little memory!

Comment: even on an embedded 600 MHz ARM with 512 MB I'd make that trade-off. Considering how single-use those devices tend to be saving CPU beats saving memory unless you run out.